# Dancer::Plugin::Auth::RBAC member registration example?

Tags: perl, cpan, dancer

I'm trying to build a membership site and I'm interested in using Perl to do this. 
I looked at the Dancer framework which seems nice, but I can't figure out how to actually create a member registration / login process using Dancer::Plugin::Auth::RBAC. The CPAN page shows some example code but nothing that is very explicit or complete. 
Googling around didn't turn up much usable except some simple examples with hardcoded login/passwords. 
Thanks
B

Answer (score 2):

Auth::RBAC is not for creating the members or the registration/management system but rather to do the actual authentication and authorisation based upon existing accounts.

Registering members is easy. You just create a suitable data store (DBIC is very nice and easy) and write a method to take details from the form, validate them and store them in the data store.